# Polars - How to replace the value of a specific row and column in df (ex. df[3,4]=12) with Polars Expression?

Tags: python, indexing, row, expression, python-polars

I know that Polars Expressions are column-wise parallelized for reading and calculating and input/change data in a DataFrame.
So, it's very fast...

However, I cannot find the **Polars Expression** that change a specific value of row and column as `df[1,'a']=12`
How can I do it?

Below is how I would like to do it.

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
        "b": [8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5],
        "c": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        "d": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    }
)
df = df.with_columns(pl.all().cast(pl.Float64))

df[7,'c']=12   
df[7,'d']=15
# I want this to below way that Polars Expressions
# => df.select(?)(
        pl.col('c').row(7) = 12
        pl.col('d').row(7) = 15
     )

print(df)
```

```
shape: (8, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c    ┆ d    │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ 8.0 ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  │
│ 2.0 ┆ 9.0 ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  │
│ 3.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  │
│ 4.0 ┆ 1.0 ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  │
│ 5.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  │
│ 6.0 ┆ 3.0 ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  │
│ 7.0 ┆ 4.0 ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  │
│ 8.0 ┆ 5.0 ┆ 12.0 ┆ 15.0 │
└─────┴─────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Answer (score 5):

You can generate a row index number with  [`pl.int_range(pl.len())`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.int_range.html#polars-int-range) (or, [`.with_row_index()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.with_row_index.html#polars.DataFrame.with_row_index))

```py
df.with_columns(index = pl.int_range(pl.len()))
```

```py
shape: (8, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬───────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ d   ┆ index │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ 8.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0     │
│ 2.0 ┆ 9.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 1     │
│ 3.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 2     │
│ 4.0 ┆ 1.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 3     │
│ 5.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 4     │
│ 6.0 ┆ 3.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 5     │
│ 7.0 ┆ 4.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 6     │
│ 8.0 ┆ 5.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 7     │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴───────┘
```

And use [`when/then/otherwise`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html#polars.when) for the conditional replacement:

```py
df.with_columns(
   c = pl.when(pl.int_range(pl.len()) == 7).then(12).otherwise(pl.col("c")),
   d = pl.when(pl.int_range(pl.len()) == 7).then(15).otherwise(pl.col("d"))
)
```

```py
shape: (8, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c    ┆ d    │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ 8.0 ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  │
│ 2.0 ┆ 9.0 ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  │
│ 3.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  │
│ 4.0 ┆ 1.0 ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  │
│ 5.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  │
│ 6.0 ┆ 3.0 ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  │
│ 7.0 ┆ 4.0 ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  │
│ 8.0 ┆ 5.0 ┆ 12.0 ┆ 15.0 │
└─────┴─────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice on the various methods that can be applied.
Let's apply and test which method is the most effective.

Comment: 4. looks nice but didn't work for me

Comment: @wordsforthewise Do you have an example?

Comment: Not anymore, sorry

Answer (score 2):

polars dataframes are immutable which means that you can't update a single cell value like in pandas. You have to replace the whole thing at once. The backend memory is smart enough not to need to copy it but the syntax is that way.

One method that jquirous didn't already cover is:

```
df = (
    df.with_row_count('i') 
        .select(
        pl.exclude('c','d'), 
        structcol=pl.when(pl.col('i')==7) 
            .then(pl.struct(c=12, d=15)) 
            .otherwise(pl.struct(c=pl.col('c'), d=pl.col('d'))))
        .unnest('structcol')
        .drop('i')
        )
```

Essentially you use `with_row_count` to create a column representing the row index, then, since you want to change two columns, you use a struct to hold both values which you will `unnest` later.  For the `unnest` to work, you have to exclude the `c` and `d` column or else `unnest` will error because of the conflicting names. Lastly, you drop the `i` column so that you end up with the same shape as you started with.

Another thing that works but is an anti-pattern is to slice the df up and then concat it together again

```
row_to_change=7
df=pl.concat([
    df[0:row_to_change], 
    df[row_to_change].with_columns(c=12.0,d=15.0),
    df[row_to_change+1:]])
```

As an aside, I'd recommend that whatever you're doing to deduce that row 7 is the row you want to change be incorporated into the change rather than making changes based on row indices. In other words you've got a step before this that told you row 7 is the row to change and now there's this step of changing row 7. You should merge this step with that step and do both at once.

Comment: I tried with your way, and it updated successfully.
now I will test the process time and I'll see if it's worth applying.
Thanks for giving me a good way.